# php upgrade to 5.4 (dynamic dropdowns don't work)

Tags: php, mysql, dynamic, upgrade

I've upgraded from php5.2 to 5.4 and now I'm having problems with my dynamic dropdowns.  Specifically, the code below literally displays ".$miscname." as the dropdown options instead of the value of $miscname.  Did I miss enabling something in the ini file.  So far, everything else is OK.

(...part of a while loop)

```
$miscname = $row['miscname'];
echo "<option selected value=".$row['miscid'].">".$miscname."</option>";
```

Comment: PHP is obviously not running here.

Answer (score 0):

I didn't have short tags enabled, within the ini file, and I'm using short tags ..